# For Looping through Numpy array gives error

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop

I'm new to python and not understanding why this for loop won't work.

```
i = np.random.uniform(0,1,100)

# this does not give error
print(i[0])
print(i[1])
print(i[2])

# this gives error
for x in i:
     print( i[x] )
```

I figure it's something to do with the line `for x in i:`. So what would be the proper way to loop through i?

Comment: `x` is not the index, it is the element itself. You should simply use `print(x)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `for x in i:`, `x` will be every elements in `i`. So your loop statement should be

```
for x in i:
     print( x )
```

If you want `x` to be the index, you should use the following code so that `x` would be from 0 to the len(i)-1 (all the index of `i`):

```
for x in range(len(i)):
     print( i[x] )
```

In addition, I recommend you to use x as the name of the array and i as the index, which is integer.

Comment: this worked! im see, x would not be the index number and is the actual element itself. python is interesting